# How to capitalise the first letter of the month in a date formula?

Tags: date, google-sheets, formatting, google-sheets-formula, capitalization

I have the `=Today()` formula to be like this: *10 de julio de 2019*

As you can see, the month julio (July) is in minus and I need the first letter upper/capitalized to be like: *10 de Julio de 2019*

I know there is `=UPPER(text)` (for capitalizing all letters) and `=Proper(text)`  (to capitalize the first letter) https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en . But these work for text and not for a date even if in the array because it transforms the date to this format:*10/7/2019*

I tried this:

```
=PROPER(today())
```

But it does give me: `10/7/2019`

I could post the month alone with the next formula and have that be proper. It works for getting the month alone, but if I use it in different cells to get also the day or the year that messes the space in the spreadsheet (it's a printable report):

```
=PROPER(text(today(),"MMMM"))
```

I also tried using:

```
=ArrayFormula(proper(text(today(),"DDDD")),proper(text(today(),"MMMM")),proper(text(today(),"YYYY")))
```

And :

```
=ArrayFormula(proper(text(today(),"DDDD")),(text(today(),"MMMM")),(text(today(),"YYYY")))
```

But they don't work.

I also used :

```
=proper(text(today(),"MMMM YYY"))
```

Which does gives me: *Julio 2019*, but then the day is missing and I have been unable to add the word 'de' between the month and year to be like : *Julio de 2019*

In the end, I expect to have the date's month for the date formula return the first letter capitalized to be like: *10 de Julio de 2019*   or "DAY", " de", "MMMM", " de", "YYYY"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this if it works for you:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(PROPER(TO_TEXT(TEXT(TODAY(), "dd mmmm yyyy"))), "De", "de")
```

---

or do it like this perhaps:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(PROPER(TO_TEXT(TEXT(TODAY(), "dd mmmm yyyy"))), " ", " de ")
```

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly for giving out : _ 10 Julio 2019_  
But iIs there a way to also add the 'de' word int he format?

Comment: The second one, `=SUBSTITUTE(PROPER(TO_TEXT(TEXT(TODAY(), "dd mmmm yyyy"))), " ", " de ") ` works perfectly fine. Thanks.